# Wordpress: Issues with post_content when using wp_insert_post

Tags: wordpress

I have a very weird problem and I would really appreciate your help with it.

I am using wp_insert_post when a user submits a post. It works fine when I submit the form (i.e. the admin of the wordpress site), but when I try the same thing with a different user (i.e. different email, not the admin of the wordpress site), it only shows part of the content I used in the post_content field.

my code:

```
$my_post = array(
'post_title'    => 'My bet',
'post_content'  => '<form action="" method="post" id=form_id>' . 'bet ID: ' . '<input readonly id=betid     type=text value=' . $bet_id . '>' . '<input id=url name=urlpath type=hidden value=>' . '</form>' ."\r\n match: " . '<span id=match>' . $_POST[event] . '</span>' . "\r\n" . $current_user->user_login . "'s Pick: " . $_POST[bet] . '</span>' . '<span id=friends>' . '</span>' ."\r\n Amount: " . '<span id=amount>' . $_POST[amount] . '</span>' . "<?php include('wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/test.php') ?>"
'post_status'   => 'publish');
```

When it is executed for the wordpress admin user (user ID=1) it works fine. when it is executed for any other user (user ID!=1) it is not showing the input fields of the form, and more important, not including the test.php I have included.

Comment: Terrible code... really. How one is supposed to work/understand/help when you have a giant one-line block? Are you able to edit that into readable code?

Comment: check for the permissions. Make some user as editor and check.

Comment: sorry that it appears as 1 line, that's because it just adds elements to a post. Pranita - what could be the issue with permissions? the post is created for everyone, just not with all the elements that I have inserted.